# Mobilefirst Push Notifications for IOS Native

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have to implement push notification on IOS native mobile application, currently I am doing small POC using Mobilefirst 8.0. I have setup all the configuration as per IBM MFP 8.0 standard. I am trying mobilefirst based sample app which is download from IBM MFP document website. I can able to login and register the users but if I am sending the notifications, I am not able to received.
I have checked logs messages in my development server. its throwing error as below,

> [ERROR   ] Couldn't send message after 3 retries.Message(Id=2;
>   Token=D60FFA8C91A465400B203424095CD5530DF2D223EC72BAE386982C0905C1AE1B;
>   Payload={"payload":"{\"nid\":\"59ef5d3\",\"tag\":\"Push.ALL\"}","aps":{"alert":{"action-loc-key":null,"body":"hi"}}})
>   Received fatal alert: internal_error [ERROR   ] FPWSE1083E: Failure
>   sending Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) notification with
>   identifier 2, device token:
>   D60FFA8C91A465400B203424095CD5530DF2D223EC72BAE386982C0905C1AE1B.
>   Received fatal alert: internal_error [err] Exception in thread
>   "pool-9-thread-3"  [err] com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error [err]
>     at
>   com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.wrapAndThrowAsRuntimeException(Utilities.java:277)
>   [err]     at
>   com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:319)
>   [err]     at
>   com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
>   [err]     at
>   com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
>   [err]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [err]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [err]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [err] Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error [err]
>     at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) [err]   at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) [err]    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
>   [err]     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
>   [err]     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
>   [err]     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
>   [err]     at
>   sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123) [err]
>     at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75) [err]   at
>   com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
>   [err]     ... 5 more

Comment: What is the Java version your MFP server uses? Provide complete build version

Comment: In VM level I am using JDK and JRE 1.8.0_171 and WAS Liberty-v8.5.9 IBM JAVA 1.7_64

Comment: mfp version -Product version: 8.0.0.00-20180718-0449

Comment: If you switch your Liberty's Java to 1.8, does this resolve the issue? Also, has push ever worked on this JVM and environment? I am trying to see if the issue is associated with the certificate or the JVM. What happens if you regenerate your certificate again - to rule out the certificate causing this.

Comment: you mean to say, I have re-generate .p12 file for push right!!!

Comment: Yes. That's correct.